# how to return count value for two match condition by grouping in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I wanted my output json to look like the below,

```
[ {
        "_id": "IT",
        "count 1": 1,
        "count 2": 1,

    },
    {
        "_id": "CSE",
        "count1": 1,
        "count2": 2,

    },

  
]
```

I tried the below query in mongoose

```
{
    $match: {

        
        riskstatus: { $in: ["Closed", "Deffered"] },
        riskstatus: { $in: [ "Open"] },
    }
},

{

    "$group": {
        "_id": "$phase",
        "count1": { "$sum": 1 },
       "count2": { "$sum": 1 },

    },

}
```

my input collection is

```
{"_id":"5df5ca73bb1c4526948e2421","comment":"test","status":"Open","phase":"CSE"}
{"_id":"5df5ca73bb1c4526948e2422","comment":"test","status":"closed","phase":"IT"}
{"_id":"5df5ca73bb1c4526948e2422","comment":"test","status":"Closed","phase":"CSE"}
{"_id":"5df5ca73bb1c4526948e2422","comment":"test","status":"Open","phase":"IT"}
{"_id":"5df5ca73bb1c4526948e2422","comment":"test","status":"Open","phase":"CSE"}
```

How to retrieve two count values for the same group with the above matching condition to achieve this result?

Latest I tried is

```
Risk.aggregate([
        { $match: { $or: [ { status: {$in: ["Closed", "Deffered"]} }, { status: {$in: ["Open"] } } ] } },
  

        {

            "$group": {
                "_id": "$phase",
                " count1": { "$sum": 1 },
                "count2": { "$sum": 1 },

            },

        }
```

Comment: Please share your request data and response data at json editor online ??

Comment: Please share output at https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a85657ec8598488abfaefefcebc5ec33

Comment: Please tell  how count of IT value 3 but give data count only 2 of IT ?

Comment: if it matches the first condition 
               " riskstatus: { $in: ["Closed", "Deffered"] " it shld retun the first count value

Comment: But you shared data having 2 value of IT

Comment: I updated.Kindly check now https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a85657ec8598488abfaefefcebc5ec33

Comment: Please tell me how to possible CSE depart have 2 count in count2 key while have 1 count according condition

Comment: kindly check my input collection that i updated in question section.CSE has 3 entries in which it has 2 record where status="open".so count is 2

Comment: Please save status common pattern

Answer (score 0):

Please use that query

```
     db.posts.aggregate(
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { 'id': '$phase', 'status': '$status' },
            count_1: { '$sum': 1 },
        }
    },
    { $project: { '_id': 0, 'depart': '$_id.id', 'status': '$_id.status', 'count_1': 1 } }
    , {
        $group: {
            _id: '$depart',
            data: {
                '$push': {
                    'depart': '$depart',
                    'count_1': {
                        $cond: [{ $eq: ["$status", 'Open'] }, '$count_1', 0]
                    },
                    'count_2': {
                        $cond: [{ $eq: ["$status", 'Closed'] }, '$count_1', 0]
                    }
                    ,
                    'count_3': {
                        $cond: [{ $eq: ["$status", 'Deffered'] }, '$count_1', 0]
                    }

                },
            }
        }
    },
      { $project: 
      {'name':'$_id','_id':0, 
      openCount: { $max: "$data.count_1"}, 
      Othercount: {  
          $add:[ 
              {$max: "$data.count_2"},
              {$max: "$data.count_3"}]

      } 

      }}

)
```